# Mysql order by top two then id

Tags: mysql

I want to show first two top voted Posts then others sorted by id

This is table

```
+----+-------+--------------+--------+
| Id | Name  | Post         | Votes  |
+====+=======+==============+========+
| 1  | John  | John's msg   | -6     |
| 2  |Joseph |Joseph's msg  | 8      |
| 3  | Ivan  | Ivan's msg   | 3      |
| 4  |Natalie|Natalie's msg | 10     |
+----+-------+--------------+--------+
```

After query result should be:

```
    +----+-------+--------------+--------+
    | Id | Name  | Post         | Votes  |
    +====+=======+==============+========+
    | 4  |Natalie|Natalie's msg | 10     |
    | 2  |Joseph |Joseph's msg  | 8      |
-----------------------------------------------
    | 1  | John  | John's msg   | -6     |
    | 3  | Ivan  | Ivan's msg   | 3      |
    +----+-------+--------------+--------+
```

I have 1 solution but i feel like there is better and faster way to do it.
I run 2 queries, one to get top 2, then second to get others:

```
SELECT * FROM table order by Votes desc LIMIT 2

SELECT * FROM table order by Id desc
```

And then in PHP i make sure that i show 1st query as it is, and on displaying  2nd query i remove entry's that are in 1st query so they don't double.
Can this be done in single query to select first two top voted, then others?

Answer (score 2):

You would have to use subqueries or union - meaning you have a single outer query, which contains multiple queries inside. I would simply retrieve the IDs from the first query and add a id not in (...) criterion to the where clause of the 2nd query - thus filtering out the posts retrieved in the first query:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE Id NOT IN (...) ORDER BY Id DESC
```

With [union](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html) the query would look like as follows:

```
(SELECT table.*, 1 as o FROM table order by Votes desc LIMIT 2)
UNION
(SELECT table.*, 0 FROM table
    WHERE Id NOT IN (SELECT Id FROM table order by Votes desc LIMIT 2))
ORDER BY o DESC, if(o=1,Votes,Id) DESC
```

As you can see, it wraps 3 queries into one and has a more complicated ordering as well because in `union` the order of the records retrieved is not guaranteed.

Two simple queries seem to be a lot more efficient to me in this particular case.

Comment: i think that MySQL doesn't support a LIMIT in the subquery, but you can use a join instead

Comment: @fthiella pls check out the link on union. It says otherwise :)

Comment: yes, the problem is not on the union query where the limit is supported, but on the `NOT IN (select ... LIMIT 2)` where it is not

Answer (score 1):

There could be different ways to write a query that returns the rows in the order you want. My solution is this:

```
select
  table.*
from
  table left join (select id from table order by votes desc limit 2) l
  on table.id = l.id
order by
  case when l.id is not null then votes end desc,
  tp.id
```

the subquery will return the first two id ordered by votes desc, the join will succeed whenever the row is one of the first two otherwise l.id will be null instead.

The order by will order by number of votes desc whenever the row is the first or the second (=l.id is not null), when l.id is null it will put the rows at the bottom and order by id instead.